# Maximum sound level differs between Ubuntu and Windows

Tags: 12.04, sound, media

Recently I've been watching lots of .mkv or .avi files in my Ubuntu and I realize that the maximum sound level is lower than what is in the Windows with `KM Player`. This difference is very noticeable in my Ubuntu and bothers me. Is there a solution to this?

I have checked all sound levels in Ubuntu, the default and `movie player` sound level.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this all boils down to suboptimal hardware and driver support in linux.
that is why in windows sound often is louder and more dynamic, because many companies dont open their hardware details for the linux community
or provide their own drivers, thus pulseaudio and ALSA must "emulate".